# Подключение к хост-машине изнутри docker-контейнера

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, apache, docker

При запуске контейнера docker не получается подключиться к базе данных postgresql. При запуске с локалки все работало. 
Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
```

Данные подключения:

```
$host = "host=35.237.11.247";
$port = "port=5432";
```

При исполнении скрипта через сервер получаю

```
pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not 
connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host 
"35.237.11.247" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? in 
/var/www/html/test.php on line 8
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что это за ip? Белый IP вашей домашней машины? Вероятно postgres не разрешено обслуживать внешние соединения?

Comment: external ip google cloud машины. Именно с нее я и запускаю докер контейнер

Comment: по умолчанию изнутри контейнера хост-машина доступна по адресу `172.17.0.1`. уточните командой `$ ip r` внутри контейнера. // или можно передать программе *docker* опцию `--net=host`, тогда сетевая подсистема не будет изолирована, и к локальным сервисам можно обращаться по адресу `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию, postgresql слушает loopback-интерфейс(localhost):

```
ss -tulpn
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port 
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       127.0.0.1:5432       *:*
```

Нужно явно разрешить слушать внешний интерфейс.

```
$ find / -name "postgresql.conf"
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/postgresql.conf
```

Меняем `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` на `listen_addresses = '*'`.

Перезагружаем сервер..

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```

Проверяем:

```
ss -tulpn
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port 
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:5432       *:*
```

---

Ещё одной из причин может быть firewall.
Кто-то фильтрует соединения к Вашей базе:

```
➜ nmap 35.237.11.247 -p5432
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-06-28 20:07 +07
Nmap scan report for 247.11.237.35.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.237.11.247)
Host is up (0.19s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.21 seconds
```

Comment: Изменил, сделал, проверил - все как вы и сказали. Подключение все равно не работает. Вы учли, что хост сервера осуществляется через docker image?

Comment: `"хост сервера осуществляется через docker image"` - это какая-то дичь. Вы хотите сказать, что сервер базы данных крутится в контейнере docker? Тогда Вам нужно расшарить порт контейнера на хостовую машину. php-контейнер, указанный в вопросе фактически ни при чём, он является клиентом и вероятно имеет доступ по сети. Или эти контейнера у вас на одном хосте? Тогда можно завернуть их в один `docker network`

Comment: вообще сам смысл docker, чтобы не было `"при запуске с локалки все работало"`. Нужно доставлять не Dockerfile, а готовые собранные образы. Желательно сконфигурированные с compose/swarm.

Comment: Нет, я задал этот вопрос, ибо проверяю возможные варианты. Моя база данных находится на сервере, с которого запускается docker контейнер. База данных в сам докер никак не входит. У меня просто есть предположение, что конфиг постгреса на моей машине, и конфиг постгреса в самом докере отличаются, и как-то нужно listen_addresses поменять и в докере в том числе. Но я не знаю как.

Comment: Что сейчас пишет `ss -tulpn`? `*:5432`?

Comment: `tcp    LISTEN     0      128   *:5432  *:*` в данный момент так

Comment: Попробуйте указать IP docker-bridge в качестве IP базы. Он похож на `172.17.0.1`

Comment: @FrostDamage, *\*:5432* — выставлять сервер баз данных «наружу» — это очень плохая практика.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, когда я писал ответ, мне казалось, что база на удалённом сервере. (иначе зачем ходить к ней по внешнему IP?) Потом казалось, что база в контейнере - в таком случае `*:5432` вполне нормальное состояние)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема подключения из контейнера к хосту по адресу хоста заключается в firewall. Отключите его или создайте соответствующие правила, которые позволят принимать соединения с адресов контейнеров для хостовой ОС.

Например:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=172.20.0.0/16 accept'
```